# Promises in functions, angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

How to implement promise into function so i can get rid off timeout, if it is even possible? I'm getting some data from factory 'Prim',function look's like :

```
$scope.getPre = function(id){

 var url = WEB_API.MainUrl + '/api/prim/' + id +'/' + $window.sessionStorage.getItem('idsom');

    Prim.getprim(function(data) {

        $scope.prim1 = data;
        $scope.prim = $scope.prim1[0];

    }, url); 

    $scope.$apply();

}
```

and the timeout i want to rid off :

```
setTimeout(function() { // it can't work without timeout
    $scope.getPre($routeParams.idprim);
}, 100);
```

Comment: Use a callback, it will be cleaner

Comment: only option is promise, there is many more timeouts in project that i have to change in promises, if i use callbacks it would be unreadable and more complex

Comment: `var promise = new Promise((res, rej) => { foo(/* callback */ res); });` where `foo` is the async thing you need to wait on which takes a callback, then elsewhere in your code where you have your `setTimeout`s you instead do `promise.then(() => /* ... */);`

Comment: The point here is not promises / callbacks / whatever, the point is synchronous  vs asynchronous. Why are relying on the timeout ? What fails when you call getPre directly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function should return a promise, so you could use `.then()` on it:

```
$scope.getPre = function(id){
    var deferred = $q.defer()
    var url = WEB_API.MainUrl + '/api/prim/' + id +'/' + $window.sessionStorage.getItem('idsom');

    Prim.getprim(function(data) 
        $scope.prim1 = data;
        $scope.prim = $scope.prim1[0];
        deferred.resolve();
    }, url);

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

And then just use it like this:

```
$scope.getPre($routeParams.idprim).then(function () {
    // Do whatever you did after setTimeout
});
```